# logarithm proof

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, logarithms

I'm trying to prove the following inequalities:

\begin{align}
\frac{b+c}{b} \geq \frac{\log(\frac{a}{b})}{\log(\frac{a+c}{b+c})}, c \in (0,1)
\end{align}

I know that $\log(\frac{a}{b}) > \log(\frac{a+c}{b+c})$ for $ c > 0$, but I'm stuck as to how to proceed with the proof. This is not a homework and is a part of larger proof. This inequality may turn out to be false.

Additional constraint is that $a > b$.

Any hints will be appreciated!

Comment: What is $a$ here? What are the constraints on $b$?

Comment: $a$ is just another variable. In the bigger picture, it may be the case that $b > a$, but I'm not so sure about it at this point.

Comment: and the numbers $a,b$?

Comment: I think $a>b$ needs to be a constraint. $a=0.5$, $b=1$, $c=0.5$ doesn't work, for example.

Comment: @Shuri2060 yes you are right. After thinking about it, the constraint should be $a > b$. I'll edit my question.

Comment: quick numerical experiment ... it seems to be true if $ a > b$ ... are you going to change your question ? ... lol ...$ \ddot \smile $

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit yes I've edited the question. I apologize for the mistake in my previous question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality holds true for every $\,c\geqslant0\,$ and $\,a>b>0$.

Let $\,x=\frac ab\,$ and $\,u=\frac cb$, then $x>1$ and $u\geqslant 0$. We apply Jensen's inequality with weights in the concave case:
$$\log\left(\frac{1}{1+u}\cdot x +\frac{u}{1+u}\cdot 1\right) \;\geqslant\;
\frac{1}{1+u}\log (x)\:+\: \frac{u}{1+u}\log(1) \\[4ex]
\implies\: 1+u\;\geqslant\;\frac{\log(x)}{\log\big(\frac{x+u}{1+u}\big)}$$
and we have equality for $\,u=0\,$ only, due to the fact that $\,\log\,$ is *strictly* concave.

Answer (score 4):

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $a>b$.

Assume
$$\left(\frac{a+c}{b+c}\right)^{b+c}>\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{b}$$
Then
$$\log\left(\left(\frac{a+c}{b+c}\right)^{b+c}\right)>\log\left(\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{b}\right)$$(as both sides are positive and $\log$ is an increasing function)
$$\implies (b+c)\log\left(\frac{a+c}{b+c}\right)>b\log\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$$
$$\implies \frac{b+c}{b}>\frac{\log\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}{\log\left(\frac{a+c}{b+c}\right)}$$
(note for the rearrangement on the last line we have to make sure $\log\left(\frac{a+c}{b+c}\right)$ is positive which is true as $\log\left(\frac{a+c}{b+c}\right) = \log\left(a+c\right)-\log\left(b+c\right)$ and $a>b$ and $\log$ is an increasing function)

---

All we need to show now is that
$$\left(\frac{a+c}{b+c}\right)^{b+c}>\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{b}$$
I haven't been able to find an elegant way, so I've resorted to calculus (the idea being to write the LHS as $y(c)$ and the RHS as $y(0)$ for some function $y$, and then showing that $y(c)>y(0)$ by showing y is a strictly increasing function).

Let $y(x)=$$\left(\frac{a+x}{b+x}\right)^{b+x}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$

Then
$$\log y=(b+x)\left(\log(a+x) - \log(b+x)\right)$$
$$\implies y'y^{-1}=(b+x)((a+x)^{-1} - (b+x)^{-1})+(\log(a+x) - \log(b+x))$$
$$\implies y'=y((b+x)(a+x)^{-1} - 1 +\log(a+x) - \log(b+x))$$
$$=y\left(\frac{(b+x) - (a+x)}{a+x} +\log(a+x) - \log(b+x)\right)$$
$$y>0 \,\,\,\forall\,x\in\mathbb{R}^+\implies y' > \frac{(b+x)-(a+x)}{a+x} +\log(a+x) - \log(b+x))$$
Let $g(x)=\log x$

Then
$$y' > ((a+x)-(b+x))(-g'(a+x)) + g(a+x)-g(b+x)$$
$$a-b>0\implies y'((a+x)-(b+x))^{-1} >\frac{g(a+x)-g(b+x)}{(a+x)-(b+x)}-g'(a+x)>0$$
Observe on the graph of $y=\log x$ that the slope of the line between 2 points ($(b+x)$ and $(a+x)$ in this case) is greater than the slope at the rightmost point. Hence $\frac{g(a+x)-g(b+x)}{(a+x)-(b+x)}>g'(a+x)$. (Alternatively, an algebraic argument can be made using the intermediate value theorem on $g'(x)$ and that $g''(x)<0\,\,\,\forall\,x\in\mathbb{R}^+$)
$$\implies y' > 0$$
Hence $y(x)$ is a strictly increasing function
$$\implies y(c)>y(0)$$
$$\implies \left(\frac{a+c}{b+c}\right)^{b+c}>\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{b}$$

Comment: The first line should read $b>a$, not the other way around. Other than that, very nice proof! (+1)

Comment: I don't see how you get the very first inequality (in the first display).  Isn't ${ab+bc\over ab+ac}\lt1$ instead of $\gt1$ if $a\gt b$?

Comment: @vrugtehagel, it's been agreed in comments that the OP meant to assume $a\gt b$.

Comment: I'm slightly confused with $a > b$ as well. For $(\frac{a}{b})^{b+c}(\frac{ab + bc}{ab + ac})^{b + c} > (\frac{a}{b})^{b+c}$, b must be greater than a.

Comment: That's a very good point... silly error by me. I hope a little adjusting should be able to fix it though............

Comment: Can't see any way to fix that for now, but if all is lost then we should be at least be able to show that the function $f(x)=\left(\frac{a+x}{b+x}\right)^{b+x}$ is increasing which I did check in wolfram before

Comment: @Hosea Fixed it - using calculus for now. Hopefully someone can find a nicer method.

Comment: @Shuri2060 Thank you for taking time to write this answer! The proof does seem slightly more complicated than first imagined. I'll wait for few more days to see if anyone has more elegant method! (+1)

Comment: @Hosea (and Shuri2060), I think I found a somewhat simpler calculus approach.  Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a\gt b\gt0$ along with $c\gt0$, we can rewrite the inequality to prove as

$$(b+c)\log\left(a+c\over b+c\right)\ge b\log\left(a\over b\right)$$

Letting $a-b=d\gt0$, we can rewrite this further as

$$(b+c)\log\left(1+{d\over b+c}\right)\ge b\log\left(1+{d\over b}\right)$$

so what we need to prove is that the function $f(x)=x\log\left(1+{d\over x}\right)=x(\log(x+d)-\log x)$ is non-decreasing for $x\gt0$.  I.e., we need to prove that $f'(x)\ge0$ for $x\gt0$.

We see that

$$\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\log(x+d)-\log x+x\left({1\over x+d}-{1\over x}\right)\\
&=\log(x+d)-\log x-{d\over x+d}
\end{align}$$

But note that

$$\log(x+d)-\log x=\int_x^{x+d}{dt\over t}\ge\int_x^{x+d}{dt\over x+d}={(x+d)-x\over x+d}={d\over x+d}$$

and thus $f'(x)\ge0$ for $x\gt0$.